# Find a matching suburb in an address

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with a list of addresses on each line

i.e.

```
COLUMN A
My Company 123 Big Street Ashgrove QLD 4111
A Better Compant PO Box 123 Sandgate QLD 4111
```

I have another sheet with every QLD suburb in it in alphabetical order in a named range called `rSuburbs`

i.e.

```
Ashgrove
BBBB
CCC
Sandgate
Zilmere
```

What formula can I write to find the closest match and dump it out, i.e. like this:

```
COLUMN A                                          COLUMN B
My Company 123 Big Street Ashgrove QLD 4111       Ashgrove
A Better Compant PO Box 123 Sandgate QLD 4111     Sandgate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula in B2 copied down

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&rSuburbs&" "," "&A2&" "),rSuburbs)`

Using " "& ensures that you don't get partial matches

Comment: That worked for me. If you have time could you expland on your answer and explain what each component is doing? It's interesting that you just concatenate a range to a string like that - what's going on there?

Comment: The weird thing is when I put `=SEARCH(" "&rSuburbs&" "," "&A2&" ")` into a cell I get `#VALUE!`. How on earth does this work?

Comment: Basically, using an arbitrarily large number with a lookup will allow it to skip errors and return the last valid value that matches. So this will look for the 2^15th value in the result array comparing the values in `rSuburbs` to those in `A2`. Since there are less than 2^15 values, it will return the last non-error. Since there is only one match, it will return the only non-error. This is complicated, but you can get tidbits with [this search](https://www.google.co.jp/#q=excel%20lookup%20bignum).

Comment: OK, so `SEARCH` can return a vector, and `SEARCH` isn't an exact search, it does a partial match, The `#VALUE!` I see as a result of `SEARCH` is simply an array that can't be rendered in a cell? When we feed the result of `SEARCH` into `LOOKUP` it looks up the same named range to turn the result a cell value rather than an array location. I _think_ I understand. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of suburbs is in column K2:6 with the heading suburbs in K1:

`{=INDEX(K:K,LARGE(IFERROR(FIND($K$2:$K$6,A2)*0+ROW(A$2:A$6),0),1))}`

<sup>Array formulas must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> -- do not try to enter the squiggly braces manually!</sup>

This will return the desired output.

Basically, figure out if each of the list is in the text in column A, return the row number of the suburb if it is, or zero if it isn't, and take the suburb of the largest index you get.

Comment: HI jmac, your solution did for me but did not use the rSuburbs range. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ah, sorry about that @ElectricLlama! You can feel free to replace `$K$2:$K$6` and `$A$2:$A$6` with `rSuburbs` as follows: `{=INDEX(K:K,LARGE(IFERROR(FIND(rSuburbs,A2)*0+ROW(rSuburbs),0),1))}` (though as usual, Barry's answer is better!)

Comment: Thanks... I probably should have realised that anyway. If you have time and don't mind, could you expand on this answer - what each function component is doing? I understand if you don't as I have already awarded the answer though.

Comment: @ElectricLlama I would explain it if Barry's solution wasn't infinitely superior in every way -- mine is a kludge -- it works but not prettily. His is created with surgical precision relying on the oh-so-many undocumented features of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a vba solution this will print the suburb name in Column B, amend to match your workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Sub splitlr()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim s As String, str As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim a As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With ws
        a = 1
        Do Until a = lr
            s = .Range("A" & a).Text
            i = Len(s)
            j = InStrRev(s, " ") - 1
            k = InStrRev(s, " ", j) - 1
            l = InStrRev(s, " ", k)
            str = Mid(s, l, (i - k))
            .Range("B" & a).Value = str
            a = a + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your iput Alistair - I wasn't after a VBA solution at this stage. Also it doesn't appear to be referencing rSuburbs, but instead splitting based on spaces? Thanks anyway.